# why aren't anonymous functions in Lua expressions?

Tags: function, lua, expression

Can anyone explain to me why the anonymous function construct in Lua isn't a fully fledged expression?  To me this seems an oddity: it goes (slightly) against the idea that functions should be first class objects, and is (not often but occasionally) an inconvenience in what is mostly a really well-thought out and elegant language.

example, using the command line Lua, with workaround

```
Lua 5.3.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2016 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> function(x) return x*x end (2)
stdin:1: <name> expected near '('
> square = function(x) return x*x end
> square(2)
4
```

Comment: "*it goes (slightly) against the idea that functions should be first class objects*" No, it doesn't. The nature of a first-class object and the nature of a grammatical expression have nothing to do with one another.

Comment: Actually (and i know this is pushing this argument to the limit and not to be taken too seriously) I could imagine a language with a new blogop type that is fully first class, but no syntax whatsoever to construct one.  If you had a variable containing a blobop then you can do anything you like to it including assign it. But it's useless. IMHO, to be useful as first class objects (in the spirit if not in the letter of the law) you need supporting syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Lua's function call syntax has some syntactic sugar built into it. You can call functions with 3 things:

- A parenthesized list of values.
- A table constructor (the function will take the table as a single argument).
- A string literal.

Lua wants to be somewhat regular in its grammar. So if there's a thing which you can call as a function in one of these ways, then it should make sense to be able to call it in any of these ways.

Consider the following code:

```
local value = function(args)
   --does some stuff
   end "I'm a literal" .. foo
```

If we allow arbitrary, unparenthesized expressions to be called just like any other function call, then this means to create a function, invoke it with the string literal, concatenate the result of that function call with `foo`, and store that in `value`.

But... do we actually *want* that to work? That is, do we want people to be able to write that and have it be valid Lua code?

If such code is considered unsightly or confusing, then there are a few options.

1. Lua could just not have function calls with string literals. You're only saving 2 parentheses, after all. Maybe even don't allow table constructors as well, though those are less unsightly and far less confusing. Make everyone use parentheses for all function calls.
2. Lua could make it so that only in the cases of lambdas are function calls with string literals prevented. This would require substantially de-regularizing the grammar.
3. Lua could force you to parenthesize any construct where calling a function is not an obviously intended result of the preceding text.

Now, one might argue that `table_name[var_name] "literal"` is already rather confusing as to what is going on. But again, preventing that specifically would require de-regularizing the grammar. You'd have to add in all of these special cases where something like `name "literal"` is a function call but `name.name "literal"` is not. So option 2 is out.

The ability to call a function with a string literal is hardly limited to Lua. [JavaScript can do it](https://michelenasti.com/2018/09/19/javascript-chiamare-funzioni-senza-usare-parentesi-(what!)), but you have to use a specific literal syntax to get it. Plus, being able to type `require "module_name"` feels like a good idea. Since such calls are considered an important piece of syntactic sugar, supported by several languages, option #1 is out.

So your only option is #3: make people parenthesize expressions that they want to call.

Answer (score 1):

Oh I see.. round brackets are needed, sorry.

```
(function(x) return x*x end) (2)
```

I still don't see why it is designed like that.

Comment: Lua wasn't designed with IIFEs in mind. You need parentheses in Javascript as well, where they are used much more frequently. In Lua, most things that would be IIFEs in Javascript are going to be `do ... end` blocks instead.

Comment: @Jasmijn: IIFEs can be useful to rebind `...`. It may still be better to use `{...}`.

Answer (score 1):

## Short Answer

To call a function, the function expression must be either a name, an indexed value, another function call, or an expression inside parentheses.

## Long Answer

I don't know why it's designed that way, but I did look up the [grammar](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#9) to see exactly how it works. Here's the entry for a function call:

> functioncall ::=  prefixexp args | prefixexp ‘:’ Name args

"args" is just a list of arguments in parentheses. The relevant part is "prefixexp".

> prefixexp ::= var | functioncall | ‘(’ exp ‘)’

Ok, so we can call another "functioncall". "exp" is just a normal expression:

> exp ::=  nil | false | true | Numeral | LiteralString | ‘...’ | functiondef | prefixexp | tableconstructor | exp binop exp | unop exp

So we can call any expression as long as it's inside parentheses. "functiondef" covers anonymous functions:

> functiondef ::= function funcbody
>
> funcbody ::= ‘(’ [parlist] ‘)’ block end

So an anonymous function is an "exp", but not a "prefixexp", so we do need parentheses around it.

What is "var"?

> var ::=  Name | prefixexp ‘[’ exp ‘]’ | prefixexp ‘.’ Name

"var" is either a name or an indexed value (usually a table). Note that the indexed value must be a "prefixexp", which means a string literal or table constructor must be in parentheses before we can index them.

To sum up: A called function must be either a name, an indexed value, a function call, or some other expression inside parentheses.

The big question is: Why is "prefixexp" treated differently from "exp"? I don't know. I suspect it has something to do with keeping function calls and indexing outside the normal [operator precedence](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.8), but I don't know why that's necessary.